# Stone Weierstrass and Runge

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, approximation-theory

Suppose $E(closed)\subset\{z:|z|=1\}$ and let $f(z)$ be a continuous function on the set $E$.
I want to show that $f(z)$ can be approximated by polynomials on $E$.

I am not exactly sure how to solve this problem, but I have a very small idea. I know that Runge's theorem cannot apply because I am not told that the function is analytic so I would have to apply the (Stone) Weierstrass theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(z) = \bar {z}.$ Claim: $\sup_{|z|=1}|f(z)-p(z)| \ge 1$ for all holomorphic polynomials $p.$ Proof:

$$\int_0^{2\pi} |f(e^{it}) - p(e^{it})|^2 dt= \int_0^{2\pi} |e^{-it} - p(e^{it})|^2 dt=\int_0^{2\pi} |1 - e^{it}p(e^{it})|^2 dt \ge 2\pi.$$

by simple orthogonality. But the latter integral is $\le 2\pi (\sup_{|z|=1}|f(z)-p(z)|)^2,$ and that proves the claim.

Comment: Another way to see that you can't uniformly approximate $\overline{z}$ by polynomials on the circle is that $\oint_E \overline{z}\; dz = \oint_E z^{-1}\;dz = 2 \pi i$ but $\oint_E p(z)\; dz = 0$ for any polynomial $p$.

Comment: $\overline{z}$ is a continuous function.  If you can't approximate it, you can't approximate arbitrary continuous functions.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm slow tonight :(

Comment: Right Robert, that's even simpler.

Comment: @Robert, one more question: the last equality ($= 2\pi i$)... is it for the whole unit circle?  If $E\subset \{|z| = 1\}$, say, a half-circle, is it still true? Anyway, I think that the idea holds...

Comment: @zhw. I believe you have proved that you cannot approximate $f$ if $E$ is the unit circle. The question is asking for a prof if $E$ is a closed subset of the unit circle.

Comment: The answer is still no, as $|z|=1$ is a closed subset of the unit circle.

Comment: @zhw. What I mean is that $E$ is a closed proper subset of the unit circle ( an arc). In this case it is actually true that you can approximate $f$ by polynomials. Why should this not be true?

Comment: If $E$ is an arc, $\int_E p(z)\; dz$ can be anything.

Comment: @smanoos If $E$ is a proper closed subset of the circle, then polynomials are dense in $C(E).$ This follows from Stone-Weierstrass and Runge. I don't see how, as proposed earlier, you can get this from just Weierstrass on some $[a,b].$